# Combining 2 worksheet change events Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

Could someone please help me combine these two events below. My goal is to get the to move my row to another sheet when "Completed" is inputted to the Column F. In addition, im looking to add a last updated date/time to column G anytime a value/string in the corresponding row is changed but i cannot figure out how to combine these. PLEASE HELP!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("B3:L5000"))
    Dim Z As Long
    Dim xVal As String
    On Error Resume Next
    

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'pervent triggering another change event

' Last Updated

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row < 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column < 2 Then Exit Sub
    Cells(Target.Row, "G") = Date
    
Next AffectedRange

'MOVING COMPLETED

    'Dim Z As Long
    'Dim xVal As String
    'On Error Resume Next
    
    If Intersect(Target, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Z = 1 To Target.Count
        If Target(Z).Value > 0 Then
            Call MoveBasedOnValue
        End If
        
          
    Next
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is only one Change event in OP. Did you miss some code?

Comment: I have the Moving Completed code which is: 
'MOVING COMPLETED

Dim Z As Long
Dim xVal As String
On Error Resume Next
    
If Intersect(Target, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 For Z = 1 To Target.Count
    If Target(Z).Value > 0 Then
        Call MoveBasedOnValue
    End If  
Next 

I also have the Last updated event which is:
 
'Last Updated
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Row < 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column < 2 Then Exit Sub
Cells(Target.Row, "G") = Date

Im a noob with this so i could be way off.

Comment: Please *edit your question* if you need to add code.

Comment: `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` (and similar lines) are exiting the Sub *after turning off events*, so any further updates will not trigger the event handler...    `Target.Row` can never be <1, so you don't need that test.   `Me` can be used in place of `Target.Parent` - in a worksheet code module `Me` refers to the worksheet.

Comment: `If Target(Z).Value > 0 Then` not checks `Completed` rather than if the value is greater than 0, or if value is text the first letter's ASCII code greater than &H30 (48). `Next AffectedRange` without For.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Target.Row = 6 And Target.Value = "Complete" Then
Target.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now(), "DD.MM.YYYY")
End If
```

You can also use GoSub and Goto if you need to ship around in the same Event Sub routine and still keeping the same Target.

Answer (score 0):

Date is a type, not a value, isn't it

You'll have to replace

```
Cells(Target.Row, "G") = Date
```

with something like

```
Cells(Target.Row, "G") = today()
```